# NSButton inside NSTableView Programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsbutton

How can I set a column of checkboxes inside a NSTableView? So far, this is what I have done, but it just puts the int 1 in the column, not the checkboxes:

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row {
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"Enable"]) {
        NSButtonCell *cell=[[[NSButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease];
        [cell setAllowsMixedState:YES];
        [cell setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
        NSCell *aCell = [tableColumn dataCellForRow:row];
        [aCell setObjectValue:cell];
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    }

    return [[data objectAtIndex:row+1] objectAtIndex:[[data objectAtIndex:0] indexOfObject:[tableColumn identifier]]];
}
```

Comment: Instead of getting the cell in `objectValueForTableColumn:...`, you should implement the `NSTableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` or `tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:` (I'm not clear exactly what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Interface Builder, drag a Check Box Cell to the table column. That will set the data cell for the column. Set up the cell however you want in its Inspector. Then delete all the code you have here that acts on the cell, and just return the `NSNumber`.

In response to your desire to do this programmatically: Interface Builder is really the way to go here. It's designed for laying out GUI objects. I'll tell you how to do it, though.

First, calling `setObjectValue:` on an `NSCell` with another `NSCell` as the argument doesn't transform the first into the second, or change the pointer values or something like that. The `setObjectValue:` method changes the [`objectValue` of the cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/DisplayingCellValues.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000071-BBCEAFCE) -- essentially, the object that it displays as text.

If you want to supply a cell for the table column programmatically, you'll need to call `-[NSTableColumn setDataCell:]` with your desired `NSCell` somewhere (`awakeFromNib` would probably be a good choice), but be warned, the table column reuses the same cell instance for every row, and just modifies it before it's drawn so it displays correctly. There's no way to set a different cell for each row in a column, UPDATE: *without subclassing NSTableColumn*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to do this programatically.

Comment: I'm trying to add a checkbox to one column of a table but as soon as I drag it in, I can no longer return strings in the tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: method for the other columns. I can't find any documentation on this, the method just requires an object (id) to be returned but I don't know what I'm supposed to return. Can I not have strings and checkboxes in the same table?

Answer (score 10):

you need to use the dataCellForTableColumn delegate method.

```
- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

   if([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualTo:@"delete"]){

    NSButtonCell *cell = [[[NSButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    [cell setAllowsMixedState:YES];
    [(NSButtonCell *)cell setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    [cell setTitle:@""];

    return cell;

   }else {
    NSCell *cell = [tableColumn dataCell];
    return cell;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: It works nice but when I drag and drop the rows of my cell, the buttons remain in the 'old' positions, they are not redrawn. How to fix this ?